# AngularJS : Argument 'ModalEditProfileController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs, controller, modal-dialog

I am working on an user profile, and would like to display a modal dialog to edit this profile. 
My view is controlled by a ProfileController in which I wrote the following code :

```
$scope.onOpenModalEditProfile=function(){
  console.info("onOpenModalEditProfile");
  var modalInstance=$modal.open({
    templateUrl:'app/profile/_edit-info.html',
    controller:'ModalEditProfileController',
    backdrop: 'static',
    resolve: {
      editUser: function() {
        return $scope.editUser;
      }
    }
  });
};
```

In the file ModalEditProfileController.js :

```
'use strict';
controllersModule.controller('ModalEditProfileController',
function($scope, 
$rootScope, 
$http, 
$modalInstance, 
growl, 
growlModal, 
User, 
editUser) {

$scope.editUser = editUser;
$scope.currentUser = User.current;

console.info("Starting ModalEditProfileController...");


$scope.onCancel = function () {
  console.info("onCancel");
  $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
```

}
);

and when I try to display the modal, I have this error :

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'ModalEditProfileController' is not a function, got undefined
```

And even before trying to display it, this one :

```
Uncaught TypeError: element.dispatchEvent is not a function
```

I read a lot about this kind of errors and nothing worked yet!
I also tried with the *jQuery.noConflict()* function without success..

I have another modal in the same window which is working perfectly and has the same syntax.
All the files are located in the same file.

I really thank you for your help, have a great day!